# How to solve the permission for NS3 hg

Tags: mercurial, user-permissions, ns-3

I am trying to install ns3 in my Mac os 10.10.3 and when I typed `./download.py` I got the following message:

```
Updating ns-3 branch
 =>  hg --cwd ns-3-dev pull -u
not trusting file /Users/username/Documents/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user username, group staff
not trusting file /Users/username/Documents/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user username, group staff
abort: repository default not found!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./download.py", line 242, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "./download.py", line 198, in main
    ns3_dir = get_ns3(options.ns3_branch)
  File "./download.py", line 29, in get_ns3
    run_command(['hg', '--cwd', ns3_dir, 'pull', '-u'])
  File "/Users/username/Documents/ns-3-allinone/util.py", line 25, in run_command
    raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['hg', '--cwd', 'ns-3-dev', 'pull', '-u'] exited with code 255
```

I dont know how to activate permission for ns3 hg.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your problem, I think you need to put:

```
[trusted]
users = root
```

in the `/Users/username/Documents/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/.hg/hgrc` file, this should work.

For additional information please read the [help on trust in Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Trust) and make sure that you've set a correct trust settings.